# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag with line break tag

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, reactjs

Imagine:

```
return (<a href="{this.props.url}">{this.props.name}</a><br>)
```

also attempted with

```
return (<a href="{this.props.url}">{this.props.name}</a><br />)
```

While the script does run without issue, the JSX compiler is upset by the `<br>` tag, since its a lone wolf in the logic and has no open/close tag it just is.

if on the other hand I remove the `<br>`

```
return (<a href="{this.props.url}">{this.props.name}</a>)
```

there is no error thrown, pretty self explanatory as far as what the issue is. The question however is how to resolve the underlying problem. how can I have that tag (or its equivalent if need be). Be added after every one of the above rendering statements.

Things to assume, this is a loop of urls/names that generate an html list of links on the page. Everything minus this factor thus far works.

The underlying issue overall is a issue of aesthetics. I am using bootstrap, and in that things are fairly uniform and I have no desire to create one-off classes or inline styles to accommodate the line-break. This is just purely for the sake of maintainability down the road.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a wrapping root tag:

```
<div>
    <a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.name}</a>
    </br>
</div>
```

Comment: Which there is a wrapping tag, this overall is a case of multiple children rendered through a loop. Primary example being, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children. So in this case to wrap the children with another parent would cause extra markup as far as bootstrap is concerned

Comment: @chris Well, react simply says no if you try to have a component with no single root tag so there's no escaping that unless you want to style the anchor with `display:block`

Comment: maybe it helps when you wrap it in a `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can render many 'tags' with a Component, but it MUST be within a 'parent tag', just like Eelke said.

Another way to do so is to declare a variable within render() function and return it:

```
render(){
    var step;
    if(this.props.gender==="male"){
        step = (
          <div>
            <p>A pessoa chamada {this.props.name} eh um homem! </p>
            <b>aqui</b>
          </div>
        );
    }else{
        step = (
          <div>
            <p>A pessoa chamada {this.props.name} eh uma mulher! </p>
            <b>aqui</b>
          </div>
        );
    }
    return step;
}
```